# Easy way to differentiate between number and letter in C

Tags: c

I'm currently reading in a file, and storing that file into a cstring. I'm using strtok to parse it out for the first few strings i'm interested in. After that, the substrings could be numbers (500,150,30) or character combinations( P(4),(K(5)). Is there an easy method in the string library to differentiate between numbers and letters? \

Thanks for the answers guys!

Comment: Don't think _number_ and _letter_: think `int` and `char`, it might seem easier.

Comment: `#include <ctype.h>` and use `isalpha()` and friends

Comment: There's also `isdigit` to tell if its a digit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that there are no other symbols (@#$%^%&*^) you can use the [isalpha()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isalpha.htm) function.

Usage:

```
   isalpha(p);// returns true if its alphabetic and false otherwise.
```

Also note that you should include `ctype.h`.

Answer (score 1):

well, if you're reading a stream of bytes and want to differentiate between numbers and letters the following can be done:

```
// returns true if given char is a character, false otherwise
bool is_letter(char c) {
    return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z');
}
```

which is easy enough to implement where it is needed. If you really want a library function, you can still use [`isalpha()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isalpha) or [`isdigit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isdigit) from `ctype.h`, which basically should do the same thing.

N.B.: you might want to choose between `bool` or `unsigned short`. I won't enter into that [debate](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/bool.html).

Comment: Nitpicking: `is_letter()` would be incorrect for [EBCDIC](http://ascii-table.com/ebcdic-table.php) encoding. The best way is to use the standard functions.

Comment: I usually agree on using the standard function, but when the taks is as simple as this one, I may do an exception… And btw, your counterexample is wrong, looking at your link my code still works, as this table is alike ASCII.

Comment: And characters in C are represented by `int`s, not `char`s (you know why).

Comment: @zmo EBCDIC is on the left column, not on the right one :)

Comment: ah, indeed, the table was'nt really clear… Anyway, I guess if you're talking with an AS400, you should have totally different `is_alpha()`/`is_digit()` functions to be able to deal with both EBCDIC and ASCII, otherwise I don't even want to imagine edge effects…

Answer (score 1):

You probably look for `isalpha` and `isdigit` library functions.